# How to merge (dynamic) numbers of lists into a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is a fast and pythonic (2.7) way to achieve the following result:
Dicts a, b are dynamic and can be more

```
original = [
    [{'a1': 'a1_1', 'a2': 'a2_1'}],
    [{'b1': 'b1_1', 'b2': 'b2_1'}]
]


# this should be the result
result = [
    ({'a1': 'a1_1'}, {'b1': 'b1_1'}),
    ({'a2': 'a2_1'}, {'a1': 'a1_1'}),
]
```

I've tried it with `enumerate(zip())` but I dit not get it..

Comment: Your `original` and `result` variables are identical since your last edit, i guess this is not intended ?

Comment: You're right - edited  once more, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your data is in the format:

```
original = [
    [{'a1': 'a1_1', 'a2': 'a2_1'}],
    [{'b1': 'b1_1', 'b2': 'b2_1'}]
]
```

You can reorganize your data into something like this:

```
x = [[list(elem.items()) for elem in item] for item in original]

# x
# [[[('a1', 'a1_1'), ('a2', 'a2_1')]], [[('b1', 'b1_1'), ('b2', 'b2_1')]]]
```

So you can regroupt it in a intermediate state like this:

```
y = list(zip(x[0][0], x[1][0]))

# y
# [(('a1', 'a1_1'), ('b1', 'b1_1')), (('a2', 'a2_1'), ('b2', 'b2_1'))]
```

And finally get your result with:

```
result = [dict(item) for item in y]

# result:
# [{'a1': 'a1_1', 'b1': 'b1_1'}, {'a2': 'a2_1', 'b2': 'b2_1'}]
```

The pattern should be the same if you have more items..

Comment: No, I think your code is on the wrong level - ```'list' object has no attribute 'values'```

Comment: it not that different. i edited for you, check it out.. hope it helps

Comment: It helps, thank you - but if after ``b2`` b3{},... added it mixes all things. but it is a good start ;-) ```[{'a1': 'a1_1', 'b1': 'b1_1'}, {'a3': 'a3_1', 'b2': 'b2_1'}, {'a2': 'a2_1', 'b3': 'b3_1'}]```